# can not ran API, which uses PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have Installed and Deleted pgAdmin several times and several versions, as I can not start the API. So, it does not work, even if followed all instructions and created a database with the correct name on my mac. Then, I installed PostgreSQL (14) with homebrew. However, in pgadmin it does not show PostgreSQL 14 as a database, and the command  `postgres -V` shows only this `postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.6 (Homebrew)`. But I have these two versions of DB. When running the API, it shows an error **incorrect error: password authentication failed for user "Postgres"**
every time when downloading the DB I did the password as 12345. What should I do now?

I tried to delete it entirely on the terminal and in an applications folder.
[here's pgAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmUI8.png)

Comment: pgAdmin has only limited abilities to autodetect servers.  If the server is not there, register it.

Comment: "When running the API,"  What API?  You already said pgAdmin has a different problem, so which API is *the* API, if not pgAdmin?